# A Word + Number Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

This is a code:

> 27 15 68 28 29 16 said that
> '53 95 62 18 65 92 22 19 7 8 74 102 90 49.'

What is the secret behind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code can be solved by:

> Replacing each number with the symbol of the element in the [Periodic Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) with the corresponding atomic number.

Doing this:

> 27 15 68 28 29 16 said that '53 95 62 18 65 92 22 19 7 8 74 102 90 49.'
>
>  ...becomes...
>
>  Co P Er Ni Cu S said that 'I Am Sm Ar Tb U Ti K N O W No Th In.'
>
>  i.e. **Copernicus said that 'I am smart but I know nothin.'**